# Is there any working alternative for creating a firebase database listener at onDestroy method?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-realtime-database

I need to remove from a table "Tabla1" all items that contain a child with a specific value "nombre", so I need to get into a for loop that compares each child. And this must be done just before the application or the activity is finished, so I need to do it in an onDestroy method (but this is not the main problem as I've found an alternative for this), and at a closing service that is called every time, the app is completely finished at onTaskedRemoved. I've been able to remove a specific child by getting to know its key, but cannot implement a loop like this: (I have implemented just the same code at many other places in code and it is working, but for some reason at onDestroy or onremovedtask methods it doesn't even step into the addListener... method)

```
public void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    databaseReference.child("Pedido").child(key).removeValue(); //This is working

    databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            DataSnapshot s = snapshot.child("Tabla1");
            for (DataSnapshot x : s.getChildren()){
                if (key.equals(x.child("nombre").getValue(Integer.class).toString())){
                    databaseReference.child("PedidoProd").child(x.getKey()).removeValue();
                }
            }
            
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });


    Log.d("Estado","onDestroy");
}
```

FIREBASE:

```
  "Pedido": {

    "-N31LUB381t6Og7puJ73": {
      "id_bebida": "null",
      "id_pedido": "-N31LOCf3UH0NkbX2jBD",
      "id_producto": "1"
    }
  },     

    "Tabla1": {
    "-N31LUB4ynUSVUzZfWAv": {
      
      "nombre": "-N31LUB381t6Og7puJ73",
      "lleva": false
    },
    "-N31LUB66wW0psAw_ap7": {
      
      "nombre": "-N31LUB381t6Og7puJ73",
      "lleva": true
    },
    "-N31LUB7381cazE2o7CX": {
     
      "nombre": "-N31LUB381t6Og7puJ73",
      "lleva": false
    }
  }
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data).

Comment: I dont know how to do that but I've just posted how the structure of the table is

Comment: Have you tried to export as explained in the previous comment?

Comment: I need to delete those items in case "nombre" value is a specific value

Comment: Okey, ive just exported

Comment: To understand better, you need to delete those items in case "nombre" value is a specific value that exists only under the `Tabla1` node, right?

Comment: Right. When I create an item at Pedido node I also asociate it's id to "nombre" of some child of Tabla1 node. So when the app is finished I want to look for that nombre (which is the id of an item of Pedido) in every item of Tabla1, and in case they are the same delete those Tabla1 items

Comment: In that example, there is a Pedido item with id "-N31LUB381t6Og7puJ73" and there are 3 Tabla1 items whose "nombre" is that id, in the code it is called "key", so I want to compare nombre with that key and then as they are the same remove them, if "nombre" didnt coincided with key then it wouldnt be removed

Comment: Is your `Tabla1` a direct child of your Firebase Database root?

Comment: Yes, it is. I think the problem comes from onDestroy method, cause i've used it this way at main activity and works correctly.

Comment: Step one is to stop ignoring potential errors and implement `onCancelled`. At its minimum that should be `public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) { throw databaseError.toException(); }`.

Comment: Just followed your advice and checked that it is not getting into onCancelled, it doesnt even get into onDataChange, so it is not repporting any error

Comment: So you say that if you're using the exact same code inside onCreate, it works fine?